# manipulation of byte data slow in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

i am trying to fetch a series of pixel colors at different offsets using this function,

```
   _getColor(ByteData rgbaImageData, int x, int y) {
var byteOffset = x * 4 + y * imageWidth * 4;
var r = rgbaImageData.getUint8(byteOffset);
var g = rgbaImageData.getUint8(byteOffset + 1);
var b = rgbaImageData.getUint8(byteOffset + 2);
var a = rgbaImageData.getUint8(byteOffset + 3);
return Color.fromARGB(a, r, g, b);
```

}

but the it is taking long time to execute, any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be that slow, but you could reduce the number of reads:

```
Color getColor(ByteData rgbaData, int x, int y) {
  var byteOffset = (x + y * imageWidth) * 4;
  var rgba = rgbaImageData.getUint32(byteOffset);
  return Color(argb);
}
```

That only performs one (potentially unaligned) read per color, and doesn't have to recombine the bytes.

Alternatively, you can change the type of your typed data to `Uint8List`:

```
  var bytes = Uint8List.view(
    rgbaImageData.buffer, rgbaImageData.offsetInBytes, rgbaImageData.lengthInBytes);
...
  var color = _getColor(bytes, x, y);
...
Color _getColor(Uint8List bytes, int x, int y) {
  var byteOffset = (x + y * imageWith) * 4;
  var r = bytes[byteOffset];
  var g = bytes[byteOffset + 1]; 
  var b = bytes[byteOffset + 2];
  var a = bytes[byteOffset + 3];
  return Color.fromARGB(a, r, g, b);
}
```

This might be more efficient than the original, but likely not a lot.

You can even interpret the original buffer as a `Uint32List`, but that only works if `offsetInBytes` is a multiple of four, since a `Uint32List` requires data to be 32-bit aligned (which is also why it maybe be slightly more efficient than `ByteData`). If `offsetInBytes` is always zero anyway, this may work for you too.
Example:

```
  var words = Uint32List.view(
    rgbaImageData.buffer, 
    rgbaImageData.offsetInBytes, 
    rgbaImageData.lengthInBytes ~/ Uint32List.bytesPerElement);
...
  var color = _getColor(words, x, y);
...
Color _getColor(Uint32List words, int x, int y) {
  var offset = x + y * imageWith;
  return Color(words[offset]);
}
```

Another reason this may be slow is that you are allocating a *lots* of `Color` objects if you traverse the entire image. If the image doesn't have that many different colors, you can choose to reuse existing color objects. If the image has a lot of different colors, caching them may just cause even more memory churn.
Example:

```
Map<int, Color> _colorCache = {};
const int _maxCacheSize = 1024;
Color createColor(int argb) {
  var result = _colorCache[argb];
  if (result != null) return result;
  result = Color(argb);
  if (_colorCache.length == _maxCacheSize) {
    _colorCache.remove(_colorCache.keys.first);
  }
  _colorCache[argb] = result;
  return result;
}
```

then use `createColor(argb)` instead of `Color(argb)`. Again, if your image has lots of different varying colors, and no large patches of the same color, then this is most likely just overhead.

Comment: how it will work if it is a Uint32List ? the offsetInBytes is always zero @Irn